# Как сделать клик по кнопке с несколькими классами при помощи JS

Tags: javascript, html, button, click

Имеется такой HTML-элемент

```html
<button type="button" class="im-send-btn im-chat-input--send im-send-btn_static _im_send im-send-btn_send" aria-label="Отправить" data-tttype="2">Button </button>
```

Нужно при помощи JS осуществить клик по этой кнопке используя классы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
document.querySelector('.im-send-btn.im-chat-input--send.im-send-btn_static._im_send.im-send-btn_send').onclick = function() {
  console.log('Вы кликнули кнопку')
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="im-send-btn im-chat-input--send im-send-btn_static _im_send im-send-btn_send" aria-label="Отправить" data-tttype="2">Button </button>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var elem = document.querySelector(
  '.im-send-btn.im-chat-input--send.im-send-btn_static._im_send.im-send-btn_send'
);

elem.onclick = function() {
  console.log('test');
}

elem.click();
```

```html
<button type="button" class="im-send-btn im-chat-input--send im-send-btn_static _im_send im-send-btn_send" aria-label="Отправить" data-tttype="2">Button </button>
```